# Attempted import error: 'react-lifecycles-compat' does not contain a default export (imported as 'reactLifecyclesCompat')

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

./node_modules/reactstrap/dist/reactstrap.es.js

Attempted import error: 'react-lifecycles-compat' does not contain a default export (imported as 'reactLifecyclesCompat').

Answer (score 2):

Just do `npm install --save reactstrap@6.5.0` no need to remove anything. Cheers!

Comment: reactstrap@7.0.2 is out with the fix for artifacts

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error now. I am not an expert, but this is how it got fixed for me.

1. Check the version of reactstrap in your package.json (I think the latest is ^7.0.0 which got released yesterday.)
2. Change it to ^6.5.0 in package.json
3. Delete nodemodules
4. Reinstall dependencies

Answer (score -1):

1. Open `./node_modules/reactstrap/dist/reactstrap.es.js`
2. Remove `reactLifecyclesCompat,` from the following line:

   `import reactLifecyclesCompat, { polyfill } from 'react-lifecycles-compat';`
3. Change `reactLifecyclesCompat.polyfill` to `polyfill` in the following line:

   `var _default = (0, reactLifecyclesCompat.polyfill)(Transition);`

Comment: really bad answer! should not be like this.. it must have proper solution

Comment: It is not a good solution but it is a last resort I felt if nothing else worked. Is it a bug in react-lifecycles-compat?